# Transforming JSON Object without root name

Tags: json, xml, xslt, wso2

I'm trying transform my JSON object with `for-each` but I don't have any root element. Here is my object, node numbers can be more.

```
[       
{
  "id": "1",
  "href": "string",
  "description": "string",
  "isBundle": true,
  "isCustomerVisible": true,
  "name": "string",
  "productSerialNumber": "string",
  "productNumber": "string",
  "startDate": "2018-11-27T13:26:22.783Z",
  "endDate": "2018-11-27T13:26:22.783Z",
  "status": "created"
},
{
  "id": "2",
  "href": "string",
  "description": "string",
  "isBundle": true,
  "isCustomerVisible": true,
  "name": "string",
  "productSerialNumber": "string",
  "productNumber": "string",
  "startDate": "2018-11-27T13:26:22.783Z",
  "endDate": "2018-11-27T13:26:22.783Z",
  "status": "created"
},
{
  "id": "3",
  "href": "string",
  "description": "string",
  "isBundle": true,
  "isCustomerVisible": true,
  "name": "string",
  "productSerialNumber": "string",
  "productNumber": "string",
  "startDate": "2018-11-27T13:26:22.783Z",
  "endDate": "2018-11-27T13:26:22.783Z",
  "status": "created"
}
]
```

And what I'm trying with my xsl transform:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <jsonObject xmlns:json="http://json.org/">
            <requestResponse>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="count(//id) > 0">
                        <returnCode>100</returnCode>
                        <returnMessage>SUCCESS</returnMessage>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <returnCode>9999</returnCode>
                        <returnMessage>BUSINESS_FAULT</returnMessage>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </requestResponse>

            <xsl:for-each select="@*|node()">           
                    <xsl:if test="id">
                        <id>
                            <xsl:value-of select="/id" />
                        </id>
                    </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>                     
        </jsonObject>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If I have root name of my object, I can handle it but I need some help here. Thanks in advance for any idea!

Comment: Not sure if you want to do it automatic, but there are some tools for this like: https://www.oxygenxml.com/doc/versions/20.1/ug-editor/topics/convert-JSON-to-XML-x-tools.html . Otherwise you will have to load the document into a variable and fn:tokenize() it. After that you would be able to loop through with an for-each and transform your json to an xml via some substrings.

Comment: Are you doing some kind of transformation of the JSON into XML before doing the XSLT transformation? XSLT 2.0 doesn't have any ability to handle JSON input, so I assume that's what you must be doing. It then depends entirely on how you are converting the JSON to XML: there are many libraries for this, and they all do it differently. If you move to XSLT 3.0 then you can control the JSON-to-XML conversion from within XSLT itself, or you can process the JSON natively without conversion to an XML node tree.

Comment: @MichaelKay Yes, I didn't declare that but I'm getting JSON input, then I'm mapping(transform) to XML. I can transform If it exists one node. But this situation my service throws me JSON array. So, i can't get variables like `//jsonObject/id` for example.

Comment: You need to show us what XML is being supplied to the transformation, because there are so many different ways of mapping JSON to XML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a no-root name array json, you can use below xslt for `<id>` tag. Key point is `<jsonArray><jsonElement></jsonElement></jsonArray>` appoach. But you need to be careful about `<jsonElement>`, it should be in a `<xsl:for-each select="//jsonArray/jsonElement">` block. For not exposuring the for each syndrome, you should not write the root element for fields in it. For example `<xsl:if test="id">`.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
        xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xmlns:ns1="http://www.qas.com/OnDemand-2011-03"
        xmlns:json="http://json.org">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <jsonArray>
            <xsl:for-each select="//jsonArray/jsonElement">
                <jsonElement>   
                    <xsl:if test="id">
                        <id><xsl:value-of select="id" /> </id>
                    </xsl:if>
                </jsonElement>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </jsonArray>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```